# Mount an hard drive at start-up

Tags: fedora, automounting, smb, kde5

I'm using Fedora 23 with KDE Plasma.
I'd like to mount automatically my hard-drive at start-up. Here is a screenshot of my situation :

[image: Screenshot of Dolphin mounting my hard-drive]

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: `fstab` is the magic word I guess?

Comment: You tell me ^^ ?

Comment: Make the second question a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

To have a device mounted on startup, you need to edit `/etc/fstab` as `root`. The format for `/etc/fstab` is as follows:

`# <file system>    <mount point>    <type>    <options>    <dump>    <pass>`

- `<file system>` is the device or remote filesystem you want to mount.
- `<mount point>` is where you would like your device or remote file system to be mounted.
- `<type>` is the type of the filesystem you are mounted. (ext4, FAT, NTFS, etc.)
- `<options>` are the mount options associated with the filesystem.

  - A common option is `defaults`, which mounts the filesystem with `rw`, `suid`, `dev`, `exec`, `auto`, `nouser`, `async`, and `relatime`. To view available options and option descriptions, look at the man page for [`mount(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).
- `<dump>` is a boolean that determines if the filesystem needs to be dumped or not. Most of the time this value is `0`. [`dump(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dump)
- `<pass>` determines the order in which filesystem checks are done at reboot time. It is common practice to have the `root` filesystem have a value of `1`, and all other filesystems have a value of `2`.

---

**For example:** Let's say I have a device plugged into `/dev/sdb1` with an `ext4` filesystem which I would like to be mounted to `/mnt/files` on boot.

I would add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system>    <mount point>    <type>    <options>    <dump>    <pass>
/dev/sdb1          /mnt/files       ext4      defaults     0         2
```

**Note:** Comments in `/etc/fstab` are specified with a `#`. The top line in the example above is not necessary, but it is good practice to keep it in the file so you can remember the format.

---

There is a man page for everything I just said. If you want more information, take a look at the man page for [`fstab(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab).

Comment: Seems to be out of date, nowadays it's more something like:
`UUID=a32880a5-6833-4341-b5f3-119765bd916c /  btrfs   subvol=root,compress=zstd:1 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone attempting to do this on Fedora 38 (KDE) and want a GUI way to do this, go to the following settings menu:

*System Settings* -> *Removable Storage* -> *Removable Devices*

Then select automount on login (or "on attach" if preferred) for all known devices. Much easier than having to manually edit `fstab`.